# Fill a ListView multichoice automatically

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-listview

I have an listView multichoice. Each row of listview have a checkbox. I have also a arraylist with id's oh each element of listView.

I need that when the activity starts the listView is filled automatically, where each  checkbox is checked or unchecked depend of id's inside of arrayList.

This is done in onCreate of activity right? But how I can do this?
I don't have code yet about this problem.....
Any idea?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

First do work on ListView with checkbox

Here is the links for the samples

[Link1](http://www.marvinlabs.com/2010/10/custom-listview-ability-check-items/)

[Link2](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#singlemulti)

[Link 3](http://www.coderanch.com/t/513608/Android/Mobile/Multiple-Checkboxes-ListView)

Next step is get checkbox is checked based on the id.., In getView() method of Adapter you can handle with the `setChecked()`

[Study here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html)